# What exactly does EwfSysprepSpecialize do?

Tags: windows, hibernate, windows-7

I would like to ask what EwfSysprepSpecialize does exactly do.

So far, I know it seems to be an entry point within the ewfcfg.dll and must be related somehow to HORM and EWF. It does not activate the Ewf protection for any volume. Also, it does not bring the system into hibernate.

I experienced, that whenever the call `Rundll32 ewfcfg.dll, EwfSysprepSpecialize` was NOT executed before I activate Ewf, the system does not automatically restart. Whereas when this mysterious routine was executed before, the system automatically restarts.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cafed8d4-b90c-43b5-8ac1-c8a99ad33800/ewfmgr-has-been-disabled-after-deploying-image-how-to-reenable-it-) someone gave the hint to use it, but I can't find any documentation about it.

Is there any expert who can provide me some information about this secret?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but one I also wanted to know the answer for so I'll leave this here.

Far as I can tell, it's primary purpose is to create the tiny type-45 partition at the end of the disk to enable EWF-RAM (as opposed to EWF-RAM-Reg). If you already have a type-45 partition, it is deleted and re-created. If you don't have enough free space, it won't do anything.

It's half of the solution for fixing EWF-related problems stemming from cloned images. The other is making sure the partition offset and disk signature registry entries are updated. In my own deployment I used a PHP CLI script and a couple disk utilities for that part.

Hope that helps!